# Не могу нормально настроить django-ckeditor

Tags: python, ckeditor, django

Помогите пожалуйста. Изображения загружаются на сервер, но не отображаются в редакторе. Я так понимаю, проблема связана с библиотекой PIL. Пробовал переустановить - безрезультатно В консоли выдает следующее:

> [22/Nov/2013 16:46:51] "GET
>   /ckeditor/browse/?CKEditor=id_content&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=ru
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 5663
>
> [22/Nov/2013 16:46:51] "GET /media/uploads/2013/11/22/ajax_thumb.png
>   HTTP/1.1" 404 2462
>
> [22/Nov/2013 16:46:51] "GET /static/ckeditor/galleriffic/css/basic.css
>   HTTP/1.1" 304 0
>
> [22/Nov/2013 16:46:51] "GET
>   /static/ckeditor/galleriffic/js/jquery.galleriffic.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
>
> [22/Nov/2013 16:46:51] "GET
>   /static/ckeditor/galleriffic/js/jquery-1.3.2.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
>
> [22/Nov/2013 16:46:51] "GET
>   /static/ckeditor/galleriffic/css/galleriffic-2.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
>
> [22/Nov/2013 16:46:51] "GET
>   /static/ckeditor/galleriffic/js/jquery.opacityrollover.js HTTP/1.1"
>   304 0
>
> [22/Nov/2013 16:46:51] "GET /media/uploads/2013/11/22/ajax_thumb.png
>   HTTP/1.1" 404 2462
>
> [22/Nov/2013 16:46:51] "GET
>   /static/ckeditor/galleriffic/css/loader.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 0
>
> [22/Nov/2013 16:46:51] "GET /media/uploads/2013/11/22/ajax.png
>   HTTP/1.1" 404 2444
>
> [22/Nov/2013 16:46:52] "GET /media/uploads/2013/11/22/ajax.png
>   HTTP/1.1" 404 2444
>
> Internal Server Error: /ckeditor/upload/
>
> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line
>   115, in get_response response = callback(request, callback_args,
>   *callback_kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py",
>   line 77, in wrapped_view return view_func(args, *kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ckeditor\views.py", line 145, in
>   upload create_thumbnail(saved_path)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ckeditor\views.py", line 88, in
>   create_thumbnail imagefit.save(handle, format=pil_format)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1458, in save
>   save_handler = SAVE[format.upper()] # unknown format
>
> KeyError: 'PJPEG'

Comment: Попробуй установи хедеры для libjpeg и после этого переустанови pil

Answer (score 3):

Возможно у вас PIL собрался без поддержки jpeg. Установите библиотеки libjpeg и libjpeg-dev (примерные названия по памяти, поищите как они в вашем дистрибутиве называются). И переустановите PIL. В конце установки он выдаёт табличку с поддержкой каких форматов он собрался. Ещё можете попробовать поставить pillow - клон PIL. Возможно он найдёт то что надо для поддержки jpeg.